# Sort membership tiers by names on index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a drivers (user table) which has a relationship with the subscriptions table. There are 3 different tiers available: Gold, Silver and a Free tier. What i want to do is group and order by tiers, so I'd have the golds together, silvers together etc in descending order.

What i have now in my controller:

```
class DriversController < ApplicationController

  def index
    order_subs = Driver.order_by_subs.all



    def gold_drivers
        Driver.select { |driver| driver.subscriptions.stripe_plan == 'price_xxx' || driver.subscriptions.stripe_plan == 'price_xxx'}
    end

    def silver_drivers
        Driver.select { |driver| driver.subscriptions.stripe_plan == 'price_xxx' || driver.subscriptions.stripe_plan == 'price_xxx'}
    end

    def free_drivers
        Driver.select { |driver| driver.subscriptions == 'null' || driver.subscriptions == ''}
    end

    @pagy, @drivers = pagy(
        Driver.joins(:profile).select(
          'drivers.*',
          '(profiles.no_races + profiles.no_poles + profiles.no_podiums + profiles.no_wins) AS score'
        ).reorder(gold_drivers, silver_drivers, free_drivers, score),
        page: params[:page],
        items: 16
    )
  end
end
```

So my thoughts were I could select the records under a variable i.e gold_drivers and then add them as I would in the reorder section in the @pagy pagination section `.reorder(gold_drivers, silver_drivers, free_drivers, score)` At the moment when i run the page I get the error `undefined method` stripe_plan' for nil:NilClass` so i'm guessing it can't find the column. If it's a free user, they won't have a record in the subscription table. Thanks

EDIT: driver model

```
  scope :is_gold, -> { where("drivers.subscriptions.stripe_plan == 'price_xxx'") || where("drivers.subscriptions.stripe_plan == 'price_xxx'") }
  scope :is_silver, -> { where("drivers.subscriptions.stripe_plan == 'price_xxx'") || where("drivers.subscriptions.stripe_plan == 'price_xxx'") }
  scope :is_null, -> { where("drivers.subscriptions.stripe_plan == ''") || where("drivers.subscriptions.stripe_plan" == null) }
  scope :order_by_subs, -> { reorder(:is_gold, :is_silver, :is_null) }
```

Comment: Don't you mean `@gold_drivers =` or `@silver_drivers =`, etc.?  You are trying to set those as variables right?  I think you really need to do some basic Ruby and Ruby on Rails tutorials because if setting variables is not something you understand you are going to really struggle.

Comment: Defining nested methods like this is not something you ever want to do in Ruby. The methods will be defined in the outer scope (DriversController) every time the method is called.

Comment: Your scopes are also completely broken. That does not even vaguely resemble actual SQL. I think your best shot here is really to show us an example of the schema, data and expected results becase this code is not redeemable.

Answer (score 0):

I have to be honest your code is incredibly confusing.  It looks like you can order by subs, but I guess you can't, I'm not sure what is working and what isn't looking at your code.  I see what you are doing from our previous conversation and this is off. Like I said in my comment, I would focus on understanding the basics here before you dive into some of this stuff.  I'm going to fix your method and explain along the way so it hopefully makes some more sense and either works, or shows you a path to getting it to work.

```
class DriversController < ApplicationController

  def index
    # because there is no @ on this it is a local variable, it will not be available in the view.  Wondering also why you didn't just use this for the select below.  Also, if you can already order by subs why would you even need to select them, wasn't that the reason for selecting them like this in the first place?
    order_subs = Driver.order_by_subs.all

    # it is my understanding you want these in the view so we add the @ symbol which makes it an instance  variable and you access those variables in the view now
    @gold_drivers   = order_subs.select { |driver| driver.subscriptions.stripe_plan == 'price_xxx' || driver.subscriptions.stripe_plan == 'price_xxx'}

    @silver_drivers = order_subs.select { |driver| driver.subscriptions.stripe_plan == 'price_xxx' || driver.subscriptions.stripe_plan == 'price_xxx'}

    @free_drivers   = order_subs.select { |driver| driver.subscriptions == 'null' || driver.subscriptions == ''}

    # Not sure where your local variable 'score' is coming from, do you need to set that first?
    @pagy, @drivers = pagy(
       Driver.joins(:profile).select(
      'drivers.*',
      '(profiles.no_races + profiles.no_poles + profiles.no_podiums + profiles.no_wins) AS score'
    ).reorder(@gold_drivers, @silver_drivers, @free_drivers, score),
    page: params[:page],
    items: 16
    )
  end
end
```

O.k so now you are setting the drivers values as instance variables which can be accessed in your view.

Comment: Yeah i tried doing other stuff with scopes like we were talking about, hence the `order_subs`. Are the scopes now no longer needed?

Comment: I have no idea what is working or not, but you don't need both.  Did you read up on either?  Ordering by sub, if it works, would probably be the best solution and it would mean you don't need anything else (if I remember you original issue correctly)